# Reputation Mismatch in data.stackexchange against profile

Tags: support

I just ran a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/130918/top-users-by-location) and it's showing my reputation lower than the salesforce.stackexchange.com profile gives me. I'm not sure why is the difference. Kindly can someone explain if this is something I don't know?

Thanks,
Madhura

Comment: I had the same experience. My guess is the database it queries isn't updated in real time. The results I received were as of a couple days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you are querying is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was 2 days ago.

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)

Comment: Ah,that's it. Thanks for the info. Didnt know about this behavior